# Использование нескольких подзапросов для вставки

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне необходимо заполнить таблицу из 6 столбцов данными из двух других.Можно ли это сделать используя 2 подзапроса? Пример :

```
INSERT INTO `global`(`coins`, `markets`, `cap`, `volume`, `cap_usd`, 
`volume_usd`) VALUES(
  (SELECT SUM(pairs) as `coins` FROM `markets`),
  (SELECT COUNT(symbol) as `markets` FROM `markets`),
  (SELECT SUM(cap) as `cap` FROM `coin`),
  (SELECT SUM(volume) as `volume` FROM `markets`),
  (SELECT SUM(cap_usd) as `cap_usd` FROM `coin`),
  (SELECT SUM(volume_usd) as `volume_usd` FROM `markets`)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как нибудь так:

```
INSERT INTO `global`(`coins`, `markets`, `cap`, `volume`, `cap_usd`, 
`volume_usd`)
SELECT coins, markets, cap, volume, cap_usd, volume_usd
  FROM (
    SELECT SUM(pairs) as `coins`, COUNT(symbol) as `markets`,
           SUM(volume) as `volume`, SUM(volume_usd) as `volume_usd`
      FROM `markets`
  ) A
  JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(cap) as `cap`, SUM(cap_usd) as `cap_usd`
      FROM `coin`
  ) B
```